# Stm32 project to IAR

Tags: stm32, iar

I have a project which is include STM32f4 HAL library and lots of code. And I have makefile for the this project.(Include gcc, g++)
I want to import my project into IAR Compiler. How can I do this without change my project. How can I convert it just by adding something on the project?

Comment: This is probably not possible, as many embedded projects contain compiler-specific code (e.g. inline assembly or function attributes) that doesn't work with a different compiler. You will probably have to adjust the code to make it work with IAR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a new project in IAR and add all the settings yourself. This is fairly straight forward and if you are not familiar with IAR it will help you learn. It is much simpler than makefiles. Of course IAR can work with makefiles as well but it is probably not the best place to start.

There will be a few compiler specific HAL files you will need to change (startup code). These are already in the STM32 HAL downloads.

Answer (score 2):

The STM32CubeMX code generation utility can generate IAR project files that work out of the box for your device. Manually adding your source file structure and custom settings (linker script, FPU etc) should be rather easy once you have that working minimal setup.